# Collatz sequence ends at 4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a Collatz sequence program using the practice projects from chapter 3 of Automate the boring stuff with python.

The program outline is:

> Write a function named `collatz()` that has one parameter named `number`.
>
> If `number` is even, then `collatz()` should print `number // 2` and return
>   this value. If `number` is odd, then `collatz()` should print and return 
>   `3 * number + 1`.
>
> Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that
>   keeps calling `collatz()` on that number until the function returns the
>   value `1`.

My code runs however it stops on 4 rather than 1. For every number I have tried so far the output goes past 1 back to 4.

example output:

```
6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1,4
```

I am using python 3.4.2

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number //2
        print(number)
        return number
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        number = 3 * number + 1
        print(number)
        return number


print ("pick a number:")

while True:
try:
    number = int(input())
    while number != 1:
            number = collatz(number)
    collatz(number)
    break
except ValueError:
        print("Error: Please enter a valid integer")
print("Magic! You are down to 1.")
```

Comment: You call `collatz(number)` again outside the `while` loop. `1` is odd, and `3 * 1 + 1 == 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `collatz()` once more after the loop finishes with 1. Just remove that line, and it works fine.

Also if you move the `"pick a number"` to the `input` function, you can avoid the new line after the question and are asked again every time, if you input an invalid value.

Additionally you should also check if the number is greater than or equal to 1, to avoid endless loops. The code to do all that would look like that:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("pick a number: "))
        if number < 1:
            print("Error: Please enter a integer greater than or equal to 1 ")
            continue

        while number != 1:
                number = collatz(number)
        # removed the additional call to collatz
        break
    except ValueError:
            print("Error: Please enter a valid integer")
print("Magic! You are down to 1.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz(number):
    number = number // 2 if number % 2 == 0 else 3 * number + 1
    print(number)
    return number

number = int(input("Pick a Number\n"))

while number != 1:
     number = collatz(number)
print("Magic! You are down to 1.")
```